# Sorting Array Based on custom object values

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I Need to `Sort` out an `array` of custom objects.

The `object` is simple, it stores an x and y co-ordinate, for example:

```
XYPointObject.xCoordinate = [NSNumber];
XYPointObject.yCoordinate = [NSNumber];
```

I have an `array` that stores up to 676 of these objects that I need to `sort` into a numerical order as in x values in numerical order, and the y values connected to the x values in order as well.  for example, if the input co-ordinates are:

```
23,5 | 
5,7 | 
1,4 | 
1,7 | 
21,8 | 
9,12 | 
16,19
```

the sorted array would have the order

```
1,4 | 1,7 | 5,7 | 9,12 | 16,19 | 23,5
```

keep in mind the max x,y co-ordinants are 25 (25,25)

Answer (score 0):

Did you even take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)?

Here's the method that you need:

```
-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
NSSortDescriptor *xSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"xCoordinate" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *ySorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"yCoordinate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray=[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[xSorter,ySorter]];
```