# Failing to sort array using custom comparator for two properties

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, ipad

EDIT:
As I figured out, there wasn't even a problem, I just used the wrong values to check my results.

I am having a little trouble comparing custom objects of my database with the goal of sorting them in a very specific order, in principal, it's pretty easy, the sort mechanism has to work with two properties of this custom object which are represented by strings, but may contain numeric values aswell.

This is the custom comparator block I am trying to fix at the moment.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [baseAry sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Obj *o1, Obj *o2) {
NSComparisonResult comp1 = [o1.attr_a compare:o2.attr_a];
if (comp1 == NSOrderedSame) {
    return [o1.attr_b compare:o2.attr_b];    
}
return [o1.attr_a compare:o2.attr_a]; 
}];
```

In the end, a list should look like this:

- 12 - 3
- 12 - 8
- 13 - 1
- 14 - 2
- 14 - 4
- 22 - 1
  etc

but using the current comparator I'm only getting a result like this one:

- 12 - 8
- 12 - 3
- 13 - 1
- 14 - 4
- 14 - 2
- 22 - 3
- 22 - 2
- 22 - 1

Is there even a comfortable way to do this with one block of code? Another approach I could imagine is splitting the list into sublists and sort these seperately and glue them together in the end, but this would probably take a higher amount of computing power

Comment: if you are returning the same value what is the need for that if loop checking the compared is same??

Comment: Your problem looks similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610434/sorting-array-based-on-custom-object-values/15611004#15611004

Comment: You can also do it as: 

   NSSortDescriptor *firstSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstProperty" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *secondSorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"secondProperty" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedArray=[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[firstSorter, secondSorter]];

Comment: As I can't answer my own question yet: I figured it out. Both of your solutions would've worked (aswell as the one I implemented), I was just displaying the wrong values for the comparison.

Thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare `attr_a` of both objects first. If they are equal, compare `attr_b` of both objects:

```
NSComparisonResult comp = [o1.attr_a compare:o2.attr_a];
if (comp == NSOrderedSame) {
    comp = [o1.attr_b compare:o2.attr_b];    
}
return comp;
```

(Your code compares `attr_a` of the first object with `attr_b` of the second object, which does not make much sense.)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized a mistake in my code in the beginning: It's exactly what you just posted. that doesn't seem to be it. I compare attr_a, if they are the same I compare attr_b and return respectively.